# How to solve this multiple nested for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

EDIT: Big edit from ealier

I have achieved: the ultimate for-loop HELL.

What it does: scans an image and finds a 40 by 40 pixel square that has every pixel within it approximately the same color.

The problem: The code doesn't work as intended. Unsure why, but all my attempts to debug are in vain.

```
    jimp.read('jeffrey.png')
          .then(image => {
            console.log(jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(0,0)))
            console.log(image.bitmap.width)
            console.log(image.bitmap.height)

                            var breakAll = false;
            var FINALX;
            var FINALY;
var doneCounter = 0;
            //40 by 40 pixels needed for qr code. Thisis barcode, so make it 40 by 80 or smthn, figure out that x thing.
            for(var x = 0; x < image.bitmap.width; x++) { 
              var breakThis = false;
              console.log(x + " is x")
              if(breakAll == true) {
                    break;
                  }
              
              var verticalStart = 0;
              for(var y1 = verticalStart; y1 < image.bitmap.height; y1++) {
                if(breakAll == true) {
                    break;
                  }
              
                var tempStandardR = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y1)).r;
                var tempStandardG = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y1)).g;
                var tempStandardB = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y1)).b;
              
                var verticalCounter = 0;

                for(var y2 = y1; y2 < image.bitmap.height; y2++) {        
                  if(breakAll == true) {
                    break;
                  }
                  if(verticalCounter >= 40) {    
                    
                      //Then do X stuff
                      //horizcountertim
                     
                      for(var y3 = y1; y3 < y1 + 40; y3++) {
                        if(breakAll == true) {
                          break;
                        }
                        breakThis = false;
                        var horizontalCounter = 0;
                        var tempStandardR3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y3)).r;
                        var tempStandardG3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y3)).g;  
                        var tempStandardB3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y3)).b;                  
                        for(var x2 = x; x2 < x + 41; x2++) {
                          
                          if(breakAll == true) {
                            break;
                          }
                          console.log(doneCounter)
                           if(doneCounter >= 40) {
                              //SUCESS!!!!!!
                              //THE SPOT HAS BEEN FOUND AT (x minus 40, y minus 40).
                              //insert other image in this image at above coordinates. Wow I highly doubt this works.
                              console.log('SUCESS!!!!!!!!!')
                              FINALX = x2-40;
                              FINALY = y3-40;
                              breakAll = true;
                              break;
                            }
                           if(breakAll == true) {
                            break;
                          }
                          var tempStandardR4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x2,y3)).r;
                          var tempStandardG4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x2,y3)).g;  
                          var tempStandardB4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x2,y3)).b;
                          if((((tempStandardR3 - tempStandardR4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardR3 - tempStandardR4) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardG3 - tempStandardG4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardG3 - tempStandardG4) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardB3 - tempStandardB4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardB3 - tempStandardB4) >= -20))) {    
                            horizontalCounter++;  
                            if(horizontalCounter == 40) {
                              horizontalCounter = 0;
                              doneCounter++;
                              break;
                            }
                            
                           // if((x2 - x >= 39) && (y3 - y1) >= 39) {
                           
                            if(breakAll == true) {
                              break;
                            }
                          }
                          else {
                            horizontalCounter = 0;
                            verticalCounter = 0;
                            doneCounter = 0;
                            console.log('donecounter reset')
                            verticalStart = y3;
                            //y2 = y3;
                            breakThis = true;
                            break;  
                          }
                        }
                        if(breakAll == true) {
                          break;
                        }
                        if(breakThis = true) {
                          break;
                        }  
                        
                      }
                    if(breakThis = true) {
                      breakThis = false;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  if(breakAll == true) {
                    break;
                  }
                   var tempStandardR2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y2)).r;
                  var tempStandardG2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y2)).g;  
                  var tempStandardB2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y2)).b;
                  if((((tempStandardR - tempStandardR2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardR - tempStandardR2) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardG - tempStandardG2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardG - tempStandardG2) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardB - tempStandardB2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardB - tempStandardB2) >= -20))) {
                    verticalCounter++;
                  }
                  else {
                    verticalCounter = 0;
                    verticalStart = y2;
                    console.log('lvl1 reset')
                    doneCounter = 0;
                    break;
                  }
                  
                }           
              }
            } 
            console.log(' done');
            console.log(FINALX + " = x")
            console.log(FINALY + " = y")
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
```

Each of the tempStandards are the RGB value for that individual pixel.
All of the for loops are to get a 40 by 40 open grid.

The issue I do see is a problem, but am baffled as to why, is doneCounter, that is supposed to ++ every time a horizontal counter has reached 40 and thus finished its horizontal check of one row of the 40 by 40 grid.

The issue when console logging doneCounter is, it console logs the same value twice, which makes no sense since its within the same for loop that has an if else statement that either adds to donecounter or resets it to 0.

EDIT: I scrapped the above code to try and remake it entirely to see if that would let it work, still failed though and not a clue as to why: Below is the updated attempt:

```
jimp.read('jeffrey.png')
          .then(image => {
            
            console.log(jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(0,0)))
            console.log(image.bitmap.width)
            console.log(image.bitmap.height)
            var breakAll = false;
            var FINALX;
            var FINALY;
            var doneCounter = 0;
            var veritcalCounter = 0;
            var verticalStart = 0;
            var horizontalCounter = 0;
            var breakAll = false;
            var breakThis = false;
            //40 by 40 pixels needed for qr code. Thisis barcode, so make it 40 by 80 or smthn, figure out that x thing.
            for(var x = 0; x < image.bitmap.width; x++) { 
              console.log(x)
              verticalCounter = 0;
              for(var y = 0; y < image.bitmap.height; y++) {
                var tempStandardR = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,verticalStart)).r;
                var tempStandardG = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,verticalStart)).g;
                var tempStandardB = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,verticalStart)).b;
                var tempStandardR2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y)).r;
                var tempStandardG2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y)).g;
                var tempStandardB2 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y)).b;             
                if((((tempStandardR - tempStandardR2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardR - tempStandardR2) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardG - tempStandardG2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardG - tempStandardG2) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardB - tempStandardB2) <= 20) && ((tempStandardB - tempStandardB2) >= -20))) {
                  verticalCounter++;
                  if(verticalCounter == 40) {
                    verticalCounter = 0;
                    for(var y1 = y-40; y1 < y; y1++) {
                      horizontalCounter = 0;
                      for(var x1 = x; x1 < x+41; x1++) {
                        var tempStandardR3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y1)).r;
                        var tempStandardG3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x,y1)).g;
                        var tempStandardB3 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x1,y1)).b;
                        var tempStandardR4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x1,y1)).r;
                        var tempStandardG4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x1,y1)).g;
                        var tempStandardB4 = jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x1,y1)).b;      
                        if((((tempStandardR3 - tempStandardR4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardR3 - tempStandardR4) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardG3 - tempStandardG4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardG3 - tempStandardG4) >= -20)) && (((tempStandardB3 - tempStandardB4) <= 20) && ((tempStandardB3 - tempStandardB4) >= -20))) {
                          if(x1 == x+40) {
                            doneCounter++;
                            if(doneCounter == 39) {
                              //SUCESS!!!!!!
                              //THE SPOT HAS BEEN FOUND AT (x minus 40, y minus 40).
                              //insert other image in this image at above coordinates. Wow I highly doubt this works.
                              console.log('SUCESS!!!!!!!!!')
                              FINALX = x;
                              FINALY = y1-40;
                              breakAll = true;
                              break;     
                            }           
                            break;
                          }           
                        }
                        else {
                          verticalCounter = 0;    
                          horizontalCounter = 0;
                          doneCounter = 0;
                          y = y1;
                          breakThis = true;
                          break;
                        }
                        if(breakAll == true) {
                          break;
                        }
                      }     
                      if(breakThis == true) {
                        breakThis = false;
                        break;
                      }
                      if(breakAll == true) {
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    if(breakAll == true) {
                      break;
                    }
                  }  
                  if(breakAll == true) {
                    break;
                  }
                }
                else {
                  verticalCounter = 0;   
                  verticalStart = 0;               
                }
                if(breakAll == true) {
                  break;
                }
              }
              if(breakAll == true) {
                break;
              }
            } 
            console.log(' done');
            console.log(FINALX + " = x")
            console.log(FINALY + " = y")
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
```

Comment: If the code works then you might be better off submitting on the Code Review Stack.

Comment: Yes, remove console.logs. Also try to reduce function calls, e.g. instead of calling `image.getPixelColor()` for the same coordinates 3 times in a block, try to call it once, or rather pre-process the image and create a matrix with just the colors you need and access that by array indices, that will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks juraai thats makes sense I'll do that.

Comment: Side question: The average image is one million pixels. So thats 3 million lines of code to run that alone(excluding the lines in that function which I dont know how many are in there), does anyone know how many lines/stuff a computer can run per second?

Comment: @SolarMike The title would get it closed on Code Review. We don't answer how to questions. The title needs to be a brief explanation of what the code is trying to accomplish. The problem might not be solvable with a scripting language such as JavaScript.

Comment: There are *many issues* in this question/code. First, the code is really *hard to understand* and to read: it is full of debugging lines, it has an unnecessary complicated logic, the indentation is not uniform, the code is quite big and not split in function as well as merged with an even-based logic. Moreover, there is no description of the code and comments does not help. Please remove the debugging lines, refactor the code to use few well-defined function, make it *reproducible* and describe what you want. We can only help you if we understand your needs.

Comment: I edited the question. Jerome Richard, I'm not sure what you mean by refactoring the code. How would I do that?